# iOS UIViewController DatePicker blocking TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll, keyboard

Ive just joined stack overflow.  I have looked over a lot of examples on here and on the internet but haven't found a solution to my problem (possibly missed it apologises if i have).

Problem - on the iPhone:

Currently I have a UIViewController on screen that has a UIView that is pinned to the top of the parent view.  Underneath it I have a TableView with various different cells.  These cells contain textfields and other controls.

So the problem is when i focus on the textfield the keyboard pops up and blocks the users view of the cell.  I have fixed that using the Keyboard Notifications Will show and hide mechanism.

However, I have a cell that contains two labels but its input view is a DatePicker which appears where the keyboard normally is.  When the focus appears on this cell the tableview doesn't scroll up.

Has anyone seen this before?

When the keyboard pops for the textfield i get notified and run the following code:

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0.0f, 0.0f, height, 0.0f);
UIView.BeginAnimations(null, IntPtr.Zero);
UIView.SetAnimationCurve(args.AnimationCurve);
UIView.SetAnimationDuration(args.AnimationDuration);
TableView.ContentInset = contentInsets;
TableView.ScrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
```

The height is calculated off the arguments from the notification.

Answer (score 0):

solution 1:

if you want to scroll the tableview when focus appears on the cell label, you can go for https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bizpickerviewcontroller or 
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/iqactionsheetpickerview

it will have delegate methods, where you can adjust your tableview position.

or

solution 2:

you can achieve the solution by adjusting the frame of the datepicker view. like when the focus comes to the label you can show datepicker view from bottom. mean while you can adjust the position of the tableiview by calculating the height of the datepicker. but you cannot adjust the position of the cell alone.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I thought I was already doing something like that.  I have updated my question with sample code of what happens when the notification for the keyboard occurs. Is this what you mean?